# Google Map doesn't appear in iron-pages

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I'm using the Polymer 1.0 new feature called iron-pages which is considered as the migration from core-pages (0.5 version ) to build a single pages admin dashboard . One of my selected items should refer to  google-map . 
The problem is that when i select the map item to show google-map section , all is gray ?
I need a solution that works on Polymer 1.0

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for: [google-map main site](https://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-map/components/google-map/) and [on github](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map)

```
<google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" fitToMarkers>
  <google-map-marker latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892"
      draggable="true" title="Go Giants!"></google-map-marker>
  <google-map-marker latitude="37.777" longitude="-122.38911"></google-map-marker>
</google-map>
```

Comment: It's not an import problem , i'm trying to make a menu that displays sections , one of those sections is that google map , when i click on its item a rendering problem happens (Gray google-map and when i scroll it will be small and not fix in the center do you understand my case ?

Comment: gotcha. what code are you using to display the map?

Comment: I've just fix the timeout to load Google Map (on-tap event) and it works for me.